# segmentation fault on default array initialization

Tags: c++

There's default [limit](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) of stack size in *Linux*, the *segmentation fault* occurs if it's exceeded.

Why does the *segmentation fault* not show up on the first one but do on the second one with nothing but one line of default array initialization below? All are compiled by *g++ -O0*.

To be clear, no heap allocation is observed on the second one by *ltrace*, and the *segmentation fault* occurs as expected in case of the assignment operation on the third one.

1)

```
int main() {
    char arr[larger_than_allowed];
}
```

2)

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<char> arr[larger_than_allowed];
}
```

3)

```
int main() {
    char arr[larger_than_allowed];
    int nums = sizeof(arr);
}
```

Comment: Stack vs. heap is an important distinction to learn.

Comment: Well, first one allocates larger_than_allowed bytes, second one allocates sizeof(std::shared_ptr<T>) * larger_than_allowed. Size of shared_ptr is at least sizeof(uintptr_t) + link counter. So, probably, value in larger_than_allowed isn't that big.

Also, array of chars is probably easier to optimize [ remove ] by the compiler compared to an array of some strange smart pointers.

Comment: @sweenish, not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even w/o optimization, *g++* warns *unused variable arr* on the first one with option *-Wunused-variable*, and *objdump* shows nothing continues with the initialization after the stack space is allocated for the array.

However, the second one receives no warning even it has that line of logically dead code. Not only is the stack space allocated for the array, but also the implicit  initialization on the items takes place, thus finally causes the *segmentation fault* at runtime.

The operation `=` on the third one tries to assign the array size to another storage place beyond the stack limit, thus certainly causes the *segmentation fault* as well.

According to the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization):

> **Implicit initialization**
>
> If an initializer is not provided:
>
> objects with automatic storage duration are initialized to
>   indeterminate values (which may be trap representations).
>
> objects with static and thread-local storage duration are initialized
>   as follows:
>
> pointers are initialized to null pointer values of their types.
>
> objects of integral types are initialized to unsigned zero.
>
> objects of floating types are initialized to positive zero.
>
> members of arrays, structs, and unions are initialized as described
>   above, recursively, plus all padding bits are initialized to zero.

It seems that the first one belongs to objects with automatic storage duration and the second one to objects with thread-local storage duration in view of *g++*.